# value collectAsMap is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to use `collectAsMap()` in the following statement:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
...
documents_input.
  filter(_ != documents_header).
  map(_.split(",")).
  map(Document.parse(_)).
  keyBy((_.id)).collectAsMap()
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
value collectAsMap is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, `com.codependent.MyApp.Document)]`
```

Any idea why or how I could turn the Array into a Map?

Comment: check the corresponding imports and see [this class doc where the method is member](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/api/core/org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed after updating the imports as Ram Ghadiyaram suggested:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you read the `documents_input`. If you read it using `sparkContext` then you should be able to use `collectAsMap`. But if you have read the `documents_input` as `Source` or any other `scala api` then `collectAsMap` won't do the trick. In that case you can use `toMap`

Comment: no need to use `toMap`.here in this case. The implicits for PairRDDFunctions detects a Two-Tuple based RDD and applies the PairRDDFunctions methods automatically

Comment: Yes I got that @RamGhadiyaram :) I just shared some knowledge for others. :)